# AngularJS Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple bar chart, but when appending the bars to the DOM I get this error

> Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'

```
$rootScope.drawChart = function (data,selector,padding){
        var max = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
        var chart = angular.element(document.getElementById("chartxx"));
        var barwidth = ((chart.offsetWidth-(data.length-1)*padding-(data.length)*10)/data.length);
        var sum = data.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
        var left = 0;
        for (var i in data){
          var newbar = document.createElement('div');
          newbar.setAttribute("class", "bar");
          newbar.style.width=barwidth+"px";
          newbar.style.height=((data[i]/max)*100)+"%";
          newbar.style.left=left+"px";
          console.log(chart);
          angular.element(document.getElementById("chartxx")).appendChild(newbar);
          left += (barwidth+padding+10);
        }
}

        var values = [85,95,120,100,200,200,230,230,60,320,23,3433,434,45,23,23];

        $rootScope.drawChart(values,"#chartxx2",5); 




<div class="wrapperx2">
        <div id="chartxx"></div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: 1. You already have chart  variable, you can use *chart* instead of this line  angular.element(document.getElementById("chartxx")).appendChild(newbar); Just: chart.appendChild(newbar);

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild()` is a method inherent to native HTML objects, aka the result of `document.getElementById`. When you give that HTML object to `angular.element` it becomes a jQuery Object. jQuery objects have a similar method called `append()`

So you can do `document.getElementById("chartxx").appendChild(newbar)` or `angular.element(document.getElementById("chartxxx")).append(newbar)`.

So that should answer your question but I can't help but ask myself : why would you do something like that when you're using AngularJS ?

### Edit

Ok so [here's a very poorly achieved version](https://plnkr.co/edit/98ArG6zTvQL61SoJ7ANF?p=preview) of what I would have done in your place (if I was ABSOLUTELY unable to use an external library, because using an external library for charts is what I would normally do). I suggest you see and try to understand how the `ng-repeat` works here and try to apply it to your case.

Comment: I am trying to create a bar chart, and appending each bar dynamically.

Comment: if I use append() the bar chart is not shown, i.e. no bars seem to be appended

Comment: Any idea how to get appendChild to work within angular?

Comment: If you want to do it the Angular Way, you should consider populating an array of bars then doing an ng-repeat on the HTML side. This requires some testing time but I'll update my answer as soon as I get a working example

Answer (score 1):

angular.element doesn't contain method *appendChild*

[angular.element doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

You can try:

```
chart.append(newbar);
```

Comment: if I do this the bar chart is not shown, i.e. bars are not appended....

Comment: In jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/f9eopqao/2/, if I change appendChild to append also stops working, need appendChild to work...